# sqlite3 count occurrences where occurrences equals

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to get the count of all occurrences in my column then filter out the occurrences if it doesn't meet a number criteria. For example, I have a table(my_table) like so

```
fruit          variety
orange         29
orange         001
orange         89
apple          82
plum           38
plum           49
```

sql query:

```
select fruit, count(*) from my_table where count(*) > 1 group by fruit order by fruit
```

this gives me an error. I want the end result to be

```
fruit          total count
orange         3
plum           2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation functions cannot be used in a `WHERE` clause. To filter using aggregation functions use a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT fruit,
       count(*)
       FROM my_table
       GROUP BY fruit
       HAVING count(*) > 1 
       ORDER BY fruit;
```